# YOLOv8 returns only 1 object's data in the results

Tags: python, yolo, yolov8

`results[0].plot()` has shown the [correct image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BabRI.jpg) with both objects of different classes highlighted.
However, the data `results[0]` returns contains data only for the first object. For example, `results[0].boxes.xyxy` contains only 4 values when there should be 8.
The debug log after prediction also thinks there is only 1 object:

> 0: 320x320 **1 pointer**, 18.0ms
> Speed: 1.0ms preprocess, 18.0ms inference, 4.0ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 320, 320)

Since `results[0].plot()` plots the image correctly (with all 2 objects!), it means that the `results[0]` contains data for all objects. I examined the whole `results[0]`, but didn't find any property behind which the second object's data could possibly hide.
Here's the code:

```
while video.isOpened():
    frame = video.read()[1]
    results = model.predict(frame, imgsz=320)[0]
    if results:
        print(results.boxes.xyxy)
    frame = results.plot()
    output.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow("yolov8", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: You are talking about **results[0]** in the description of the problem, but in your code, you already assigned a variable **results** to results[0]: `results = model.predict(frame, imgsz=320)[0]`. If after that you refer to the results[0], what you will actually get is results[0][0] - the box coordinates of the **first** detected object, not of all the detected objects.